# Connecting to an Intersystems Cache DB through Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, intersystems-cache

I was wondering if it was possible to use the Intersystems ODBC Driver to connect to an Intersystems Cache DB through Oracle SQL Developer? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Because:

1. SQL Developer is Java, so you would need JDBC Driver (JAR)
2. We don't support this DBMS for migrations so we don't support this database type

Answer (score 0):

While you may not be able to connect directly, you may utilize InterSystems Caché's native SQL Query Builder if you're needing help in building queries. That said, Caché does have a JDBC driver that may be used as well. Although, I'm not familiar with Oracle SQL Developer.

More information may be found on the [Using the Caché SQL Gateway](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_gateway) documentation page.